# Prevent codeigniter session library from sending set-cookie header parameter if autoloaded

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, http-headers

I have a codeigniter based website and occasionally I have controllers that are called via AJAX and return JSON values. The problem is since I've already autoloaded the session library anything that's sent as a response from codeigniter has the

```
Set-Cookie  ci_csrf_token=65d0857a89345g5sg5695e71fa687b14c; expires=Sat, 09-Jul-2011 17:00:29 GMT; path=/
```

header parameter set. This seems like unneccessary bandwidth overhead, is there any way to prevent codeigniter from sending this header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without modifying the Session class: it does not expose control over that header in the [published interface](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

In addition, that cookie is not generated by the Session class, but by the [Security](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html) class. You will have to disable CSRF protection, which is unfortunately not something you can do using the published interface on a per-request behavior.